# Are there any surviving manuscript of books written by the scholars listed below?

Tags: sahaba, books

Are there any surviving manuscript of books written by the scholars listed below?

- Abu Bakr As-Siddique
- Umar ibn al-Khattab
- Uthman ibn 'Affaan
- Ali ibn Abi Talib
- ibn Mas'ud
- ibn Abbas
- ibn Umar
- Anas bin Malik
- 'Abdullah bin 'Amr bin al-'Aas
- Mu'adh ibn Jabal
- Abu Ayyub al-Ansari
- Jabir ibn 'Abdullah
- Abu al-Darda
- Abu Sa'id al-Khudri
- Ubayy ibn Ka'b
- Abu Musa al-Asha'ari
- Zayd ibn Thabit
- 'Abdullah ibn al-Zubayr
- 'Aisha bint Abi Bakr

Comment: If the question is too broad, I will split it to multiple questions.

Comment: Surviving is somewhat ambiguous as most of the knowledge was spread by oral transmission. But we have quotes that some sahaba had some own copies of Quran/hadith etc.. Else if you mean something we still have in hands right now at least as a copy of a copy ... I guess with the exception of the Quran the answer is clearly no!

Comment: @Medi1Saif That's also what I thought. But I once saw on the internet that    ibn abbas wrote a book about theology. I can't remember where. So, I thought maybe such thing exist.

Comment: There's a tafsir attributed to ibn 'Abbas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanwir_al-Miqbas

Comment: The question indeed looks like it is too broad, but I wonder if there would be a surviving document of those people no matter if it wsa really a manuscript written by them or something transmitted from them.